# Function involving combinations and conditions: {1, 2} → {1, 2, 3}

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients, combinations

[image]

Can someone help me understand this problem? Apparently the total number of functions is 6.

$$ ={2 + 3 -1 \choose 2} $$
$$ ={4 \choose 2} $$
$$ =6$$
I'm pretty confused so any detail of the problem will be thankful. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we send $1$ to $1$ there are 3 places to send 2 (namely 1,2,3).

If we send $1$ to $2$ there are only 2 places to send 2 (namely 2,3).

Finally if we send $1$ to $3$ there is only 1 place to send 2 (namely 3).

That gives 6 in all.

Another way to look at this problem is that the outputs, say $u,v,$ for the inputs 1,2 respectively must only satisfy $1 \le u \le v \le 3.$ If we let $x=u-1,y=v-u,z=3-v$ then $x+y+z=2$ where each of $x,y,z$ is restricted to be non-negative. Then by the "stars and bars" method we choose two positions for the + signs among the 4 places (including the x, y totaling 2, see stars and bars for a better explanation) we have $\binom{4}{2}=6$ ways.

Comment: What if the condition is now: a ≥ b instead of a > b? what would the new result be?

Comment: @Steve If we say $a \ge b$ it doesn't change anything, since if it happens that $a=b$ then $\alpha(a) \ge \alpha(b)$ is automatic.

Comment: @cofeemath ohhh I see. But it will change for (a < b)/(α(a)=<α(b))

Comment: I think one has to have some kind of restriction on $a,b$ for the "conclusion" involving ordering of the outputs to make sense. If we were to just drop the conditions altogether the conclusion would be (1) true if it happened that $\alpha(a)=\alpha(b)$, (2) true or false, one each, if it happened that the two outputs differed. I don't think for example replacing the original > by < in the "assumption" above the bar in your screenshot would make a difference in the count, only in which ones ended up contributing to the count.

Comment: Yes. I have a similar problem which is (a ≤ b)/(α(a) ≤ α(b)) and the answer for this problem is 2^3 = 8. So i was wondering with this new restriction will it be the same answer if: (a < b)/(α(a) ≤ α(b))? It will be the same since a=b right?

Comment: Steve: I'll have to think about that, you're saying that for each $a \le b$ it is required that $\alpha(a) \le \alpha(b),$ did I get that correctly? Because right now I still see only 6 like that. Could you list the 8 different functions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30492/discussion-between-coffeemath-and-steve).